# Pandas Dataframe Indexing questions

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, slice

I have to select rows in a df based on an Id number, the id number can be common to multiple rows such as-

```
SearchId,colA,colB,colC...
1, a, b, c, 
1, c, d, e,
1, d, f, w, 
3, e, e, s
3, a, f, s, 
4, v, c, v,
```

I have tried the following-

1. `df[df.SearchId%3==0]`
2. `df[df.SearchId==3]`

Each time I either get

1. IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series key provided
2. Only the last row with the concerned SearchId

How can I get all rows with a particular search id?

Thanks!

Comment: Does `df.loc[df.SearchId == 3]` work? Is SearchId your index?

Comment: What version pandas are you using? Your second code snippet should've worked if SearchId is indeed a column

Comment: have you tried `df[df.SearchID=='3']`?  The searchID could of been stored as a strings instead of integers

Comment: @ZJS that may explain a single match if SerchId is of mixed dtypes but is a good point, could you edit your question with the output from `df.info()`, also if searchID was your index then `df[df.index == 3]` would also have worked but you may have a mixture of strings and ints/floats in your data

Comment: @EdChum - I tried that, but didn't work. I am using Pandas 0.13.1, I could try upgrading and then maybe it should work?

Comment: @ZJS SearchId is an int64 type. I haven't specified SearchId as the index for the df, should I be doing that first? I can see that there is a method in Pandas 0.14.1 to set the index.

Comment: @user3930246 try upgrading, if that fails edit your post with output from `df.info()` and post some raw data and code you used to create the dataframe, if the data is too large then you may need to post a link to google drive or dropbox or similar

Comment: @user3930246 - Upgrading to Pandas 0.14.1 solved the issue! Thanks to all of you, very surprised that this functionality - df[df.searchid==1] - was not working in Pandas 0.13.1

Comment: @EdChum thanks for pointing this out, it was my first time asking a Q on stackoverflow

Comment: @user3930246 no worries, it'll take time to learn the etiquette here like all new places, there should be an empty tick mark under the voting arrows, tick it to mark it as answered, I've upvoted your Q+A so you have enough rep to vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to Pandas 0.14.1 solved the issue! Thanks to all of you, very surprised that this functionality - df[df.searchid==1] - was not working in Pandas 0.13.1